# How do I import a csv file with a column of guids into sql server table with a column of type uniqueidentifier?

Tags: sql-server, csv, import, ssms

I am trying to import a CSV file into SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  In the CSV file I have one column of GUIDs.  When I go to import the CSV file with the Import Wizard, I get the following error.

[image]

I have tried importing the GUID without braces and with braces.  Both ways result in the same error.  `Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Guid' (mscorlib)`  Is there anyway to import a value from a csv file into a uniqueidentifer column?

Here is an example of the top row of my csv file:

```
Id,AccountGuid,PaymentDate
1,{CF40F790-E080-4F2A-905A-0002C0E19CA2},8/31/2021 7:32
```

I logged the issue with the Microsoft SQL Server docs team on github as well.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/6956

Comment: Just to clarify, you tried enclosing the guid value in `{` and `}` already? This would need to be done within the source csv file prior to import. The reported error is a bit obvious. It is treating the field within your source csv file a `System.String`. Which does not match up to the [SQL Server Data Type Mappings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings) for the `uniqueidentifier` of your database type. In order to import to a `uniqueidentifier` column you need your source to be importing the data as a `System.Guid`. Hence the error.

Comment: @trenton-ftw I guess I could rephrase my question to how do you make a System.Guid inside a csv flat file if the braces don't work with the import wizard?

Comment: Instead of using 'Import Flat File' option, you can use the 'Import Data' option to import this data. I was able to do this using your sample data. Just make sure to change the source (flat file) data type for `AccountGuid` to `DT_GUID`. That should work unless you REALLY want to use the 'Import Flat File' option. In which case I am not sure I could help.